# Jquery find/Contains and replace table cell value

Tags: jquery, html-table

[image]

I want to check all rows of a table's first column if a text exists and if it does I want to overwrite the value in the second cell of the same row. I tried a lot and couldn't get to it. I use jQuery 1.7.1.

```
<table id="tbl">
 <tr>
   <td>sakthi</td>
   <td>1</td>    
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>pushparaj</td>
    <td>2</td>
 </tr>
</table>


$('#tbl >tr').each(function() {
  if($(this).find('td:contains'+sakthi+''))
    { 
      var oldVal = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();//find value from first td
      $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(+oldVal + +5);//replace the same value
    }

     $('#tbluom >tbody').append('<tr><td>' + UOMCaption + '</td><td>' + UOMQty + '</td></tr>');
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter`

```
$("#tbl tr td:first-child").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf("sakthi") > -1;
}).next("td").text(function() {
    var currentText = $(this).text();
    console.log("Current Text: " + currentText); 

    return currentText + " changed";
});
```

`.text()` can accept a function callback. So, inside this callback, you can grab the current value, modify it, then return whatever you want your new value to be.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7jmz/1/

Comment: Its working in finding the text, i want to overrite the value of the next td with some value. Can you help me on that too ? .text("Found it!"); instead of this, .text(currentvalue + new value); will work ?

Comment: What is `currentvalue` and `new value`?

Comment: some sample value.first td has 'sakthi' and second td has '1', if sakthi is found, i want to do something with '1'.

Comment: I will add the image for helping you

Comment: now look at the image, when i added the 'Box' again, i want to replace the box and add the 'Qty' instead of creating a new row ]

Comment: First i added 'box' with '2' as QTY, again i added 'box' with '2' as qty. I want only one column 'box' and sum of QTY in the second td. o.e., 2+2 = 4. I mean instead of writing value to the next td, i want to get the value of the same and modify it.

Comment: This would do @tymeJV Thanks for the help. saved me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34453/discussion-between-codebrain-and-tymejv)

Comment: is it possible to have if else statement inside this ?